# How to print Fpdf MultiCell adjacently

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fpdf

This is my code.Assist please.

```
    foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($row as $field) {

            $this->MultiCell($header[$i][1], 6, $field, 1,0,  'L', true);
            $i++;

        }
        $this->Ln();
    }
```

It is displaying data downwards.

Comment: how many data to the right (column) do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$current_y = $this->GetY();
$current_x = $this->GetX();
$this->MultiCell($header[$i][1],5,$field,1,'T', false,'T');
$this->SetXY($current_x + $header[$i][1], $current_y);
```

Hope this will work fine.

Comment: It is showing data across the page now.The only problem is that it is overwriting names instead of printing in new lines.